# Error editing form with dynamic drop-down list - Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Friends, in my registration form for a new product at the bank, I have the categories and subcategories fields. The subcategory value is only populated after choosing a parent category. This works perfectly, however when I want to edit the product, the subcategory value does not carry the database value. It comes empty. I would like to bring the same! My code looks like this:

```
<?php
$categories_list = [];
$subcategorias_list = [];

   foreach ($categories as $category) {
   $categories_list[$category->id] = $category->name;

   foreach ($category->subcategories as $subcategory) {
   $subcategories_list[$category->id][$subcategory->id] = $subcategory->name;
    }
   }
?>

   <small>Select Category</small>
   <?= $this->Form->control('category_id', [
            'class' => 'form-control form-control-user',
             'id' => 'category',
             'label' => false,
             'required' => true,
             'options' => $categories_list,
             'placeholder' => 'Category',
                                           ]); 
?>

<small>Select Subcategory</small>
<?= $this->Form->control('subcategory_id', 
[
            'class' => 'form-control form-control-user',
            'id' => 'subcategory',
            'label' => false,
            'required' => true,
            'options' => [],
            'placeholder' => 'SubCategory',
            ]); 
?>
```

My js looks like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    var subCategories = <?= json_encode($subcategorias_list); ?>;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#category').change(function() {

            var categoryId = $(this).val();

            var subCategoriesObject = subCategories[categoryId];

            $('#subcategory option:gt(0)').remove();
            var subCategoriesSelect = $('#subcategory');

            $.each(subCategoriesObject, function(key, value) {
                subCategoriesSelect.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", key).text(
                    value));
            });

        });
    });
    </script>
```

I appreciate any comments and if anyone can give an idea to bring the value in the edit form.

---

Update:

```
<?= $this->Form->control('subcategory_id', 
[
            'class' => 'form-control form-control-user',
            'id' => 'subcategory',
            'label' => false,
            'required' => true,
            'options' => $subcategories_list,
            'placeholder' => 'SubCategory',
            ]); 
?>
```

but, in this way, it returns all categories registered in the database without considering the linked category.

Comment: By "bank value" do you mean "subcategory_id"? Is that a field of the entity you're editing? If so, I'd guess that there's nothing showing up there when you load the page, because you're loading the page without any options in that field.

Comment: In my add.ctp it works perfectly. The subcategory is empty. When the category is added, it loads the list of subcategories linked to the category. I copied and pasted it in edit.ctp, but it comes empty. I wanted to bring the category and subcategory value from the database.

Comment: I tried to add 'options' =>$subcategories_list. In this way, it returns all subcategory records in the database, regardless of the linked category.

Comment: So, pass only the subcategories that you need then? Your PHP code already separates them, so just like your JS code does, use the current category id, ie something like `$subcategories_list[$this->Form->getSourceValue('category_id')]` (it should be noted that `getSourceValue()` must be called _after_ `$this->Form->create()`).

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly it!